# Is it practical to store a gasoline powered scooter in an apartment?

Tags: scooter

From my experience with gasoline powered tools they are quite "dirty" - fuel and oil spill rather frequently and also there's a rather annoying smell of gasoline around. I'd expect the same from a gasoline powered scooter.

How realistic is it to own a scooter without having a garage and store the scooter in an apartment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is hearsay, but I have a couple of friends who store a scooter and a 125 learner motorbike in their apartments, and they don't leak any oil or petrol - they are quite new though, so what I would advise is to have a good look at the scooter to see how old it is - if the engine is old it may have worn seals etc which may leak.

In any case, get yourself a wooden board with a sheet or cloth overlay to park it on, that way you also avoid getting the floor dirty from the tires etc.